# Change form background color if any field was changed

Tags: javascript, html, css, forms

So I have this big, complex page with several forms, some of them are quite large.
The page is filled with JavaScript code that performs some actions on the forms inputs.

I would like to have a visual feedback when a form has some inputs changed from its original value.
Ideally, some light background color, by using only CSS.

Comment: Post your javascript that does the input updates and changes. and maybe your html code as well.

Comment: Put it in a jsfiddle or plnkr so it is easy to see and modify.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
document.getElementById('form-id').onchange = function() {
    //tweak css here
};
```

[Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4EJfm/)

Answer (score 1):

You can use plain javascript to set a special class for a couple of seconds to highlight the change, and then remove it.

HTML:

```
<div id="MyElement">Some Stuff</div>
```

Javascript:

```
// On data changed:
document.getElementById("MyElement").className = "highlighted";
setTimeout(function() { document.getElementById("MyElement").className = ""; }, 5000); // remove highlight after 5 seconds
```

make sure you have a proper CSS class to reflect that. CSS:

```
.highlighted
{
    background-color: yellow;
}
```